# Why use parens instead of backticks for executing a command 'in situ'?

Tags: bash, shell-script, backticks

I have recently started to shift my shell scripting from utilizing backticks to parens to execute a command *in situ* and use the results in something else. Eg:

```
for line in `cat file`
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Now I use parens, substituting thusly:

```
for line in $(cat file)
...
```

What is the actual difference between the two methods, and why is paren substitution considered better than backticks?

Comment: (pedantry follows) Note that in bash, you can replace `$(cat file)` with `$(< file)` that is performed entirely in the shell (saving precious microseconds otherwise wasted spawning a cat process).

Comment: (pedantry continued) [Never, ever, ever use `for` to parse something line-by-line.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: @grawity - this is a contrivved example entirely to showcase the difference in the two approaches

Comment: Also, [BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) regarding this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no functional difference, however `$()` makes nesting a bit nicer and easier to follow. Consider this silly example:

```
$ echo `echo \`echo \\\`echo foo\\\`\``
foo
```

vs

```
$ echo $(echo $(echo $(echo foo)))
foo
```

Now consider doing it with a complex series of commands that do something useful ;).